# IMAP GMAP by IMAPX run forever

Tags: c#, gmail-imap, imapx

I tried to get unread email from Gmail by IMAP protocol. I found ImapX library and it ran perfectly this morning. But this afternoon I delete so many mails in my inbox folder and run again, the app browse in 30 minutes without responds. I just wonder if 30 minutes for searching email is too long. For more clear, here is my codes I used.

> var client = new ImapX.ImapClient(Server,Port, SSLRequired);
>               if (client.Connect())
>               {
>                   if (client.Login(User, Password))
>                   {
>                       var a = client.Folders["INBOX"].Search("UNSEEN",ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Full, 200).ToList();
>                       return a;
>                   }
>               }

And, I want to know what the number "200" means. I saw that when I set the number equal 200, the API get 200 emails from server. So it simply is the number of email I want to get?

Comment: 200 is the number of messages to be downloaded. Judging by your code, you are using `MessageFetchMode.Full` to download, which means the messages will be fetched completely, including all attachments. This can take a lot of time, depending on your connection and the messages you have in your inbox,

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's exactly the root cause.